# how to "multiply" a vector of x columns with a matrix of x columns?

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen

Suppose I have the following vector and matrix:

```
v = [0] [1] [2] [3] [4] [5]

m = [0, 0] [0, 1] [0, 2] [0, 3] [0, 4] [0, 5]
    [0, 0] [0, 1] [0, 2] [0, 3] [0, 4] [0, 5]
    [0, 0] [0, 1] [0, 2] [0, 3] [0, 4] [0, 5]
    [0, 0] [0, 1] [0, 2] [0, 3] [0, 4] [0, 5]
```

For matrix multiplication, the number of columns in the first matrix must be equal to the number of rows in the second matrix. Given that the vector has 6 columns and the matrix has 4 rows, I cannot use matrix multiplication.

What I would like to do is to multiply v over each row of m (i.e. element-wise multiplication), sum the resultant product for each row so that the output is:

```
[summed product for row 0 of m]
[summed product for row 1 of m]
[summed product for row 2 of m]
[summed product for row 3 of m]
```

1. Does the operation which I am looking to perform here have a mathematical name?
2. How could I perform this operation using the Eigen library? Is there a specific function for it or do is it just doing it "manually" (doing elementwise multiplication by row then summing)?

Thanks

I have looked online but couldn't see anything helpful.

Comment: In describing your output, it's not clear what you mean by "summed product for row 0 of m".

Comment: Can you please spell out what should happen in terms of scalar operations, maybe a plain old C-style loop?

Comment: Are you perhaps trying to do ```m (v^t)```? with ```v^t``` the transpose of ```v```, i.e., a column vector identical to ```v```.

Comment: @Homer512 for every row of m, you multiply each element of that row by the corresponding element of the v. once you have done this, you sum each resulting product to come up with a number for that row of m.

Comment: But … that's just the matrix-vector product `m * v` with `v` being a column vector, right?

Comment: Also note that `Eigen::Vector` is already a column vector, so it's really just `m * v`

Comment: What you describe is exactly matrix multiplication, multiplying 4x6 matrix and 6x1 vector (6 rows, one column), producing a 4x1 vector.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the long introduction section of the [documentation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMatrixClass.html), the `Vector` classes in `Eigen` are implemented in terms of the `Matrix` class with a single column -- otherwise know as a column vector. Similarly, the `RowVector` classes map to a `Matrix` with a single row.

Based on this understanding, the vector (`v`) is a `6x1` matrix and the matrix (`M`) is `4x6` matrix. You can achieve the desired result with the matrix multiplication `M x v` which is `4x6 x 6x1` resulting in a `4x1` matrix.

This is demonstrated with the following code which manually validates that the the matrix multiplication computes the expected summations.

### Sample Code

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Eigen>

using std::cout, std::endl;

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    Eigen::VectorXi vec{{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }};
    Eigen::MatrixXi mat{{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 },
                        { 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 },
                        { 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18 },
                        { 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24 }};

    cout << (mat * vec) << endl << endl;

    for (auto i = 0; i < mat.rows(); ++i) {
        int sum{};
        for (auto j = 0; j < mat.cols(); ++j)
            sum += mat(i, j) * vec(j);
        cout << sum << endl;
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
 91
217
343
469

91
217
343
469
```